# get results from mysql table while matching results from another

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get result if id match in both tables, currently i have 2 table with structure below

1- **checkin_bonus** TABLE

```
| user_id |

| 2   |
| 5   |
| 1   |
```

2- **user_pages** TABLE

```
| user_id | score |

| 2       |    100  |
| 3       |    300  |
| 6       |    600  |
```

**Desire Results:** if user_id of table checkin_bonus match any user_pages user_id return result in example case **user_id & score = 100** should displyed 
i am doing something like this but no success

**My app is MVC Based**

```
 Model.php

// Checkin Pages
       public function checkinpagesL()
{
return $this->db->select('SELECT user_id FROM checkin_bonus AS c 
AND user_id FROM user_pages AS u JOIN WHERE c.user_id = u.users_id ');
```

### }

```
View.php
  <?php
                foreach($this->checkinpagesL as $key => $value) {?>
              <tbody>
                <tr> 
                <td><?php echo $value['user_id']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $value['score']?></td>
            </tr>
              </tbody>
              <?php }?>
  </table>
```

It will help me alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually whats your field name?? Is it user_id or users_id?

if it is user_id, then please replace join on clause with u.user_id and try.

```
SELECT u.user_id as id FROM checkin_bonus AS c 
JOIN user_pages AS u ON c.user_id = u.user_id 
where c.user_id > 18 ORDER BY c.user_id DESC
```

Comment: user_id & score both

Comment: little issue found please review question again i edit it

Comment: SELECT u.user_id as id,u.score as score FROM checkin_bonus AS c 
JOIN user_pages AS u ON c.user_id = u.user_id 
where c.user_id > 18 ORDER BY c.user_id DESC

Comment: In your model you need to replace your SELECT query with this one and try.I think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

INNER JOIN is what you are looking for

```html
SELECT * FROM checkin_bonus cb
INNER JOIN user_pages up ON cb.user_id = u.users_id 
where cb.user_id > 18 ORDER BY cb.user_id DES
```

Comment: i also tried this -> return $this->db->select('SELECT user_id FROM checkin_bonus cb LEFT JOIN user_pages up ON cb.user_id = up.users_id where cb.user_id > 18 ORDER BY user_id DESC'); -> still no success

Comment: Try it with INNER JOIN

Comment: What is not working...  i am not getting all user_id's from user_pages that match with user_id of checkin_bonus

Comment: gonna try inner join

Comment: My mistake, it's INNER JOIN not sure why I said LEFT JOIN

Comment: What does not working mean, this query works. Please show the output of the query

Comment: #1052 - Column 'user_id' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: ... Updated the query, you should know the basics because it's a pretty easy problem to understand

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Join` for this

```
SELECT c.user_id,u.users_id FROM checkin_bonus AS c 
INNER JOIN user_pages AS u ON c.user_id = u.users_id 
where c.user_id > 18 ORDER BY c.user_id DESC
```

Comment: have you run this in phpmyadmin. This is a running query. Please see see at phpmyadmin and if it not run then check coulmns name is right or not. :)

Comment: // Analysis 
        public function analysisL()
    {
        return $this->db->select('SELECT *FROM user_pages where user_id > 18 ORDER BY id DESC');
    }
   // Checkin Pages
           public function checkinpagesL()
    {
return $this->db->select('SELECT c.user_id,u.users_id FROM checkin_bonus AS c INNER JOIN user_pages AS u ON c.user_id = u.users_id where c.user_id > 18 ORDER BY c.user_id DESC');

    }

Comment: // analysis code function is working fine, while i am stuck on // checkin pages

Comment: is there are records in checkin_bonus which have id's greater than 18 as well as some id's which are greater than 18 present in user_pages table. once try to same code by removing where condition

Comment: even this not working ->  function checkinpagesL() { return $this->db->select('SELECT c.user_id,u.users_id FROM checkin_bonus AS c INNER JOIN user_pages AS u ON c.user_id = u.users_id '); }

Comment: user_id > 18 used to hide id pages less than 18 nothing, the main goal is to get score of id's match please take a look i edit & improve question

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'u.users_id' in 'field list'

Answer (score 0):

try this just use join

```
SELECT cb.user_id,up.user_id FROM checkin_bonus as cb
 JOIN user_pages as up ON cb.user_id = up.user_id 
 where cb.user_id > 18 ORDER BY cb.user_id DESC
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'cb.user_id,up.user_id FROM checkin_bonus as cb JOIN user_pages as up ON cb.user' at line 1

Comment: remove the * and try

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.user_id as id FROM checkin_bonus as c join user_pages as u on c.user_id =u.user_id WHERE c.user_id>18 ORDER BY c.user_id DESC
```

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'u.users_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'u.users_id' in 'on clause'  -- What do you think this means? You could try to understand the errors SQL gives you

Comment: change it to  'u.user_id'

Answer (score 0):

You should use below query to get your desired result.

```
SELECT A.user_id, SUM(B.score) as total
FROM checkin_bonus A 
JOIN user_pages B 
ON A.user_id = B.user_id
GROUP BY A.user_id
```

Comment: By using sum you can get total score he got. In future user can get more score.